# Socket.io using default namespace with some custom namepsace, not working

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to use default namespace '\' for connecting general android application sockets with Socket.io , but I want to make custom namespace for website like '/web' but when client with io.connect('/web') it connects to default namespace.

```
basically i want authorization of all, but not for /web namespace.
here is my code

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, next) {
  //some handshaking data to varify connection
}

io.of('/web').on('connection', function(socket, next) {
  //HERE i want to SKIP verification
}


but I got request on default instead of /web.
```

Comment: Could you please update the post with the code?

Answer (score 1):

socket.io `connection` event will trigger for `/`default namespace on all socket connections.

Later events from the client will only trigger on the namespace you are connected to.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this statement? I found a problem like this in my socket but I'm not sure